# How to grep first 3 letters in a line

Tags: grep

How can i grep the first 3 letters of the below output and echo the result.

example:

```
more /etc/group |grep -i 1900
```

i get the below result.

```
h10shm:x:1900:h10adm
```

I just want the first 3 letters (in above output h10) of the about output and echo the output.

Regards,

Satvik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU `grep`, try:

```
$ grep -iPo '^...(?=.*1900)' /etc/group
h10
```

If you don't havec GNU `grep`, try:

```
$ grep -i 1900 /etc/group | grep -o '^...'
h10
```

Or:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\(...\).*1900.*/\1/p' /etc/group
h10
```

Or:

```
$ awk '/1900/{print substr($0,1,3)}' /etc/group
h10
```

Comment: Better use `.{3}` than `...`

Comment: @GillesQuenot That's interesting.  Why?

Comment: If you need to match 64 chars, you will type `.` x 64 ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot  Yes, of course, that would be the better way for long sequences.  On the other hand, (A) `.{3}` requires four characters while `...` takes only three and (B) `.{3}` works only with extended regex (or else one needs `.\{3\}`) while `...` is compatible with _either_ BRE or ERE.

Comment: I would say that `.{3}` notation is more flexible, it'll also allow to define dynamic ranges like `.{5,10}` , `.{,3}`. Secondly, `-i` flag is not needed when matching digits

Answer (score 0):

What happened to cut?

```
more /etc/group | grep 1900 | cut -c-3
```

or

```
more /etc/group | grep 1900 | cut -c1-3
output: h10
```

Works with fields as well, `-d` is your divider, `-f` is field number

```
more /etc/group | grep 1900 | cut -d":" -f1
output: h10shm
```